# OpenCV - SURF Feature Comparison

Tags: c++, objective-c, graphics, opencv, computer-vision

I am curious about how the `OpenCV` Feature descriptors are compared. For instance, I can use `cvExtractSURF()` to get a list of features and their 64-bit (or 128-bit) descriptors, where can I find out how two descriptor can be compared?

In stepping through some sample code, to me it looks like two of my "matched" features have very different descriptors (at least by numerical values).

Has anyone ever figures out how to take two descriptor arrays and compare them?

Googling hasn't helped too much...

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OpenCV 2.1 sample file find_obj.cpp, two methods are presented:

- the built-in C++ Flann function(flann give aproximate solution and works faster), I don't know exactly how it works, but it is documented [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html#fast-approximate-nearest-neighbor-search).
- a simpler C function (findPairs()) which finds the nearest neighbor by computing a simple euclidian distance between descriptors (look at the compareSURFDescriptors() function). The laplacian may also be used as a first indicator of similarity, as matching points have not the same laplacian (1 or -1). This sample is available [here](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/opencv/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/tags/2.1/opencv/samples/c/find_obj.cpp&view=markup).

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at the paper [Local invariant feature detectors: a survey](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.157.4126%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=17XdTPf6KcboOc6RhYUP&usg=AFQjCNGd1DWRyq2ibXoiz-tVwS7NEdtUCQ&sig2=JhrCpvcws04-hIcaAAMQ_Q). It's a great paper with a description of widely used feature detectors, including SURF.

Comment: I actually saw that paper. I was hoping to see the code along with it, so I can see how it is actually implemented. However, none of those academic papers seems to open source their code. Disappointing, because, reinventing their work is never trivial.

Answer (score 3):

One effective method I found (and this is inspired from some OpenCV sample code) is - 
Use a k nearest neighbour search with K=2 to find 2 matches for every descriptor in the query object. now, if distance(1st match) < 0.6*distance(2nd match), consider the 1st match as a 'good match'.

The reason why you need this and why a simple 1 nearest neighbour search won't suffice is because that gives a LOT of false-positives.

Answer (score 2):

SURF features are 64-dimensional unit vectors. A natural way to compare two feature vectors is by computing their dot product. If it's close to 1, they have strong positive correlation (=they are similar). If it's close to 0, they're nearly orthogonal (no correlation). If it's less than zero, they have negative correlation. Depending on your application, you might either consider that a match too (in which case you would take the absolute value of the dot product) or consider it worse than orthogonal.

Try computing some dot products and see what results you get.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way OpenCV searches for matched features. I calculated dot products for set of points that OpenCV considered matches and not matches, and the dot products were all over the place.